# Remap dirs and files in git? Kind of clientspec in P4?

Tags: git, perforce, git-submodules, git-subtree, perforce-client-spec

There is a *large* project which is stored in a remote GIT repository in the way:

```
root/
   |
   *
   module1/
         |
         * include/
         |       |
         |       * lib1/
         |       |     header1.h
         |       |     headerN.h
         |       * libN/
         |             headerX.h
         * sources/
                 | 
                 * lib1/
                 |     file1.cxx
                 |     fileN.cxx
                 * libN/
                 ...
```

The product is built from these libraries. Build system automatically downloads the sources, remaps each folder in the way that each library's sources directory is put near the corresponding header files on a disk, i.e.:

```
 lib1/
   include/
       header1.h
       headerN.h
   sources/
       fileN.cxx
   CMakeList.txt
```

**When the library is mapped to disk in this way it could be built**. This structure is due to historical reasons (Perforce aka P4); it worked in Perforce because of **Clientspec.txt** file where it was possible to define such remap rules on repository clone.

Currently when the repository is cloned from ***origin/master*** it is not possible to build only one library in the project w/o preliminary step to create corresponding symlinks manually. When such symlinks are created it is not possible to modify the source code there because the connection between files and .git is lost.

**Question:** is it possible to clone *origin/master* to local directory with remapping directories on the fly **and** with ability to preserve theirs connection with git (= being able to modify/rename/move files correctly?

I have researched *git submodule* and *git subtree* but seems they do not feet since they are for different purposes.

Thanks!

P.S. Currently it is not possible to affect on *origin/master* and on the server side at all.

Answer (score 0):

Currently no. Subtrees must be in a subtree with no other sources in that path. Otherwise when you split, you'll end up grabbing the files that don't belong to that subtree.

This is however a common request, and I think it may end up requiring some sort of p4 clientspec type of solution (but that's purely my opinion and I'm not that motivated to contribute that change to git right now). If I run into the same problem, maybe I will someday try to fix it. In any case it happens so much, it's bound to be addressed by someone.

You could try to have the separate depots in 2 separate clones that don't have any overlap, and somehow merge the two together using something like AUFS, and then just go back to each isolated copy to handle the checkins. You'll also probably not want to create any new files in the mix folder. That whole workflow is a mess.